# İ think we have faıled the [turkey-test] and we should burnınate ıt

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

The tag [turkey-test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/turkey-test) has four questions: one question asking what the Turkey test is, and three other questions with only a small number of net votes.

**Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

Per the tag wiki excerpt:

> The Turkey Test is quick test whether internationalization (in particular date and number formatting and text sorting and comparison for different countries) is correctly implemented in a software.

This means that it isn't purely about what happens with "İ" and "ı", but other issues as well. I think that the questions (apart from possibly the most popular one) are ultimately about internationalization, not about the Turkey Test.

**Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

Yes, it's more on-topic than "kıttens".

**Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

Nothing that can't be expressed with other tags.

**Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

See my answer to the first burnination criteria.

Comment: í hέαrtıly sυppört thìs εvent ór prò̩dücτ.

Comment: It's below 50 questions so we can just retag the 4 questions

Comment: the low vote is no measurement for a tag, than you can also close mysql and 1 million other tags.

Comment: @nbk See [the tag wiki for the burninate-request tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/burninate-request/info) for information about 50 questions.

Comment: @HereticMonkey i really don't mind if a tag exists or or not, my comment referred to *only a small number of net votes* and i think almost all tgas have that. my personal opinion: no one is misusing it and it eats no bread let it live

Comment: I don't see any problem with this tag. At *most*, I could be persuaded to synonymize it with [[tag:internationalization]]. Burnination is ridiculous.